# Average of a section of a column

Tags: rstudio

I have a huge dataset that is broken down into counts per tree. So there are 15 counts made per tree. I need to make an average of counts of egg.scars (column name) within each tree. I don't want an average of the whole column like I keep getting, I need an average egg scar count per tree.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can extract specific rows of a column by doing `eggs[1:5,5]` where `5` is your column and `1:5` are the rows from 1 to 5 and eggs your **dataframe** and then do `mean(eggs[1:5,5])`

Comment: thanks for your answer.
my dataframe is holly and includes loads more columns but I need to group the data per tree and find the average of the columns once they are grouped. extracting rows just breaks down a huge dataset (there are 40 trees with 15 counts each) and makes it more difficult to calculate an average. 
Is there any way to calculate the average per tree as one line of code instead of breaking the dataset down first?